# Is there a Sticky Note application?

Tags: software-recommendation, notes, stickynotes

On Windows 7, there is this Sticky Note app that will always start itself up and show itself in the same place with all the text you have written when you boot Windows up. You can also have multiple instances of the Sticky Note.

Do we have an equivalent app for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ubuntu 10.10 and below

- Sticky note comes with ubuntu installation.
- To use sticky notes,right click on your panel and then choose Add to Panel...Drop down and select sticky notes and then click on Add.
  [image]
- After adding the sticky note application on your panel, right click on the sticky Notes application and choose New note.
  [image]
- Now you can see sticky note in your Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are called Sticky Notes.

Just right click on the panel -> click *Add to panel...* and add **Sticky notes**.

good luck!