# Tomboy Alternatives

Tags: software-recommendation, tomboy

In Windows exist an application named Post-It! Notes. It's a very complete program: it allow to use reminder, show the notes that were opened before shutdown the PC, task manager, ...

Do exist a complete note application for Linux?

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for Tomboy alternative, I'll suggest: [Zim](http://www.zim-wiki.org)

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few note taking applications that works on Ubuntu. I believe some of them have task lists and reminders. do not know about the shutdown part but some are extensible so features can be added.

**Wunderlist**

Works on iPhone, Android,Desktop computer or online.

Read more: http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/

**KeepNote**

A fairly good note taking system with image support.

Home page: http://keepnote.org/

**tiddlywiki**

Just one single javascripted HTML page you customize and use with your browser and off you go, the advantage of this is that you get tables and images and other fancy HTML stuff. Many variations of this system exists also has plug-ins you can use to extend them.

Home page: http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

**Notecasepro**
keeps all your notes in one file, security feature, image support.
The older version of this, 1.9.8 called notecase, is available in the 10.10 repositories, I do not know if this is the case with newer releases of Ubuntu. you may want to try any one of them.

home page: http://www.notecasepro.com/

**CherryTree**

If you keep a lot of programming code notes this has some nice preformatting features that are quite useful.

Home page: http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/

**Emacs Org mode**

Very nice Table feature with pure text, good output to Latex,
Even spreadsheet calculations can be done. Can be installed from repositories, just search for org-mode in your package manager.

Some tutorials for Org:
http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html

**zim desktop wiki**

Highly recommended and I must add, my favourite.

Supports linking in place or importing (copy to notes folder)images such as .png, .jpg and other common bitmap formats also supports the vector format .svg, so you can link or import all those .svg drawings you want to reference in your notes. Excellent Latex and Html Export.

With latex system and dvipng installed a Latex equation plugin 
is availabel to include nice mathematics in your notes.

Home page: 
http://zim-wiki.org/

Zim in action:
http://zim-wiki.org/screenshots.html

Comment: It would make more sense to put your favorite one on top, so that anyone can read it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Gnote](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnote) also. It's in the Software Center and I hope it fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

[**Org-mode**](http://orgmode.org) is an Emacs mode for note taking and much more. It can do everything Tomboy and Gnote can and it can also link notes to a calender and supports export to LaTeX.

First I used Gnome's sticky notes, then I switched to Tomboy, then to Gnote and finally to Org-mode. It takes a little bit more time to learn Org-mode but after you have [learnt it](http://orgmode.org/guide/index.html) you will found it more powerful and efficient.

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install org-mode org-mode
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nevernote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/) is an open-source note taking program. I think it works compulsorily with an Evernote account, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sticky Notes. See this related question for details:

- [Is there a Sticky Note application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19886/is-there-a-sticky-note-application)