# Is there a Post-It note program?

Tags: software-recommendation, notes

The title pretty much says it all. I'm wondering if there is a good **post-it note** program for Ubuntu 12.04.

I prefer using `apt-get install` but if you can direct me to one in the software center that is fine too.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/19886/is-there-a-sticky-note-application?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few programs that can do that. One of the most well-known is Tomboy, and Screenlets is another option.

## Tomboy

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tomboy

[image]

Installation

Part of the default Ubuntu installation

Tomboy works great with Dropbox!

## Screenlets

Other program is through Screenlets:

1. In terminal type

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:screenlets-dev/ppa`

then
`sudo apt-get update`

and finally

`sudo apt-get install screenlets`

2. Go to Application > Accessories > Screenlets
3. In the Screenlets-manager window select the screenlet "Lipik"
   (click on it)
4. If you want notes to automatically start on log-in check the checkbox "Auto start on login" (bottom-left side)
5. click "launch/add" (left side)
6. if you do not want notes to stay always above other windows,
   right-click on the top of note > Window > uncheck "Keep above"

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402946)

Answer (score 2):

I use xpad (available in USC). You have to white list it so you can see the icon in the notification area, however.

```
sudo apt-get install xpad
```