# Is there a Sticky Note Application similar to Windows Sticky Note?

Tags: software-recommendation, stickynotes

**similar question** [Is there a Sticky Note application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19886/is-there-a-sticky-note-application)

but not able to find this sticky-notes in **Ubuntu 12.10**

On Windows 7, there is this Sticky Note app that will always start itself up and show itself in the same place with all the text you have written when you boot Windows up. You can also have multiple instances of the Sticky Note.

tried **Xpad** but it is not that good :(

So do we have any equivalent app for Ubuntu 12.10 ??

Comment: Can you describe more in detail, i.e. what you are missing in xpad? I have no idea, what the Windows PostIts look like, and how they might feel different.

Comment: @PaulHänsch That windows sticky note looks so much better than xpad - it actually looks like a post-it instead of a big fugly yellow window. I wish there was a way to make xpad or something look like that - **good looks**, **highly flexible**, **synced** - that'd be perfect.

Comment: this should not be marked as a duplicate question as the similar question refers to Gnome 2 sticky notes which is not available in Gnome 3.

Comment: use reminder note from http://getremindernote.com

Answer (score 16):

You can try lipik widget for [screenlets](http://www.screenlets.org/index.php/Home) (**This widget does not work on Ubuntu 14.04**)

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lipik-screenlet
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Doesnt work on Ubuntu 14.04. At the third step mentioned above, it says: Unable to locate package `lipik-screenlet`.

Comment: @Tachyons as Rahul Desai says, it doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5):

There was a "Sticky Note" application installed by default, but i believe it has now been removed.

There are [several others available](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=sticky+notes), but i believe [**XPad**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xpad) is the most commonly used (and highly rated) option.

Comment: Although the question specifically excludes XPad from consideration, as a user of Windows Sticky-Notes, I still suggest/support/promote XPad as THE Linux alernative.